# Dodecahedral K3?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces, elliptic-surfaces

In pondering
[this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58800/period-integrals-of-the-fiber-of-elliptically-fibered-k3-manifolds)
MO question and in particularly its 1st answer,  and answers to
[this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76307/a-k3-over-p1-with-six-singular-a-1-fibers) recently posed, I realized there ought to be a dodecahedral K3 surface $X$.
This $X$ would fiber as an elliptic surface over   $CP^1$
with  12 singular fibers, each of type $I_2$. The corresponding singular points on $CP^1$
would form  the vertices of the icosahedron (centers of the dodecahedron). The automorphism group of
this $K3$ will then project onto the symmetry group of the dodecahedron.  Do you  know this
$K3$?   Do you have a reference?

Comment: I could use some help getting the URLs to these questions
appear as a link in the question -RM

Comment: Done (also tweaked your AG tag)

Comment: Edited only to tweak the remaining tags.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a pretty K3 with icosahedral symmetry and 12 singular fibers each of type II (so a double root of the discriminant but with additive reduction); would that do?  It's $y^2 = x^3 + P(t)$ where $P$ has icosahedral symmetry.  Explicitly one can take $P(t) = t^{11} - 11 t^6 - t$.  This surface is isotrivial (i.e. with constant $j$-invariant, here $j=0$), and is closely related with the isotrivial surface of Chahal, Meijer, and Top, which also has $j=0$ but with $a(t) = t^{12} - 11 t^6 - 1$.  Both surfaces attain the maximum of $18$ for the Mordell-Weil rank of an elliptic K3 surface over ${\bf C}(t)$.  The Chahal-Meijer-Top paper is [on the arXiv (9911274)](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911274), and is published in *Comment. Math. Univ. St. Pauli* **49** (2000), 79–89.  My recent student G.Zaytman studied the icosahedral surface and its Mordell-Weil lattice in the course of his thesis research.

**EDIT** Come to think of it, this is up to isomorphism the unique elliptic K3 surface over ${\bf C}(t)$ with icosahedral symmetries acting on the base: for the narrow Weierstrass form $y^2 = x^3 + a(t) x + b(t)$ to have icosahedral symmetry, the same must be true of the coefficients $a$ and $b$; but $a$ has degree $8$, so must vanish identically, while $b$ has degree 12 and is thus determined up to a scalar factor.

Comment: Is it obvious that the group action on ${\mathbb P}^1$ lifts to the $K3$ surface? if it does, then there is a ${\mathbb Z}_5$ that fixes a singular fiber, so in particular it fixes the singular point. On the other hand, the action on near a fixed point has to be analytically of the form $(x,y)\mapsto (ax, a^{-1}y)$ for $a$ a $5$-th root of 1 and I'm having trouble reconciling these two facts.

Comment: Yes, it lifts.  Put the singular fiber at $t=0$ (as the formula I gave does for one of the fibers) so the surface is $y^2 = x^3 + t Q(t^5)$ for some polynomial $Q$.  Then if $a^5=1$ the automorphism $t \mapsto at$ of the $t$-line lifts to $(x,y,z) \mapsto (a^2 x, a^3 y, a t)$.

Comment: Noam, thanks for the Chahal et al ref. Page  4, sec. 3, par. 2 asserts that putting  $P(t)=A(t^6 -b)^2$ in your representation  above gives a K3 with  6 singular fibers of type IV.  The corresponding 6  zeros of  P lie on a hexagon so don't have the octahedral symmetry of my  MO question of last week (that you'd  answered).  But the zeros of  $P(t) = t (t^2 +1) (t^2 -1)$
form the vertices of the octahedron.
Might the elliptic surface for this P  be Hirzebruch's  K3 with the
octahedral symmetry? (How does one compute $p_g$ from $P(t)$?)  



Comment: @Richard: That's a good thought, but no, it's not the same.  Yes, it's an elliptic K3 surface (as long as $P$ has no zeros of order $6$ or more, $y^2=x^3+P(t)$ is K3 for $6 < \deg P \leq 12$), but it can be shown that if such a surface $X$ attains the upper bound of $20$ on the rank of the Néron-Severi group ${\rm NS}(X)$ then the intersection pairing on ${\rm NS}(X)$ has discriminant $-3n^2$ for some integer $n$, whereas the Hirzebruch surface has discriminant $-16$.  There's more ways for a K3 surface to have octahedral symmetry than icosahedral; ... [continued due to 600-character limit]

Comment: [continued] I may edit my answer soon to describe the octahedral surfaces and where the octahedral model of Hirzebruch's surface fits this picture − and also to explain how to nail down the lift of the icosahedral symmetries of ${\bf P}^1$ to $y^2 = x^3 + (t^{11} - 11 t^6 - t)$.